# Using functions from multiple classes by including them under a namespace

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, namespaces

I am trying to write a program that incorporates code from a classmates. My code looks something like this

```
Class Class1 {
...
}

Class Class2 : public Class1 {
...
}
```

My partner's code is identical in that it has a base and derived class setup with the exact same desired function as my program, just written a little differently. Now we want to combine those and pull data from each to make an entirely new class by using a namespace. Does this concept work?

```
namespace MyCode {
   Class1; Class2;
}
namespace HisCode {
    Class3; Class4;
}
Class New {
    using MyCode::function1;
    using HisCode::function2;
    void function3();
    ...
}

int main () {
    New Thing;
    Thing.function3();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO.   Could you edit your question to correct the obvious syntax errors ? E.g. `class` keyword must be lowercase, and the class definition be followed by a `;`.  And without `public`, in a class everything is private.   And also clarify where function1 and function2 are defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that namespace and class are not the same.

**Namespace composition**

So you could very well define some non-member function in a namespace:

```
namespace MyCode {
   ...
   void function1(int a) {}  // not a member function!!
}
namespace HisCode {
    class Class4 {};
    void function2(int b) {}
}
```

And then define in another namespace (or in the scope of a function) an alias `using MyCode::function1`.

**Classes**

But in a class, all functions are member functions.  So you can there only introduce a `using` clause for member functions.  And only for member functions that are inherited from some base classes:

```
class OurNewClass {
public:
    using MyCode::function1;   // OUCH !!! Error:  not a member function
    void function3() {};
};
```

So if you want to combine member function in classes, you need some kind of inheritance:

```
class OurNewClass : public MyCode::Class1, public HisCode::Class3 {
public:
    void function3() {};
};
```

You don't need in principle the `using` clauses: all the public functions of both parent classes are visible from the outside.  You need the `using` clause, only if you would have some naming conflicts, to disambiguate.

Here a full [example online](http://ideone.com/76AQCd)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to my mind is to write it like this:

```
Class YourClass {
   virtual YourFoo() { /* DO STUFF */ }
}

Class HisClass {
   virtual HisFoo() { /* DO STUFF */ }
}

Class NewClass : public YourClass, public HisClass {
   NewFoo() { /* DO STUFF */ }
   CombinedFoo() {
      YourFoo();
      HisFoo();
   }
}

int main() {
   NewClass A;
   A.YourFoo();
   A.HisFoo();
   A.NewFoo();
   A.CombinedFoo();
}
```

Not sure if making all methods of your classes virtual is valid solution in your case but would work surely. Only when inheriting from 2 classes you must make sure there are no functions with same name in those 2 or at least they are not both virtual.